# openCV error: can't found the images .jpg

Tags: python, opencv

```
for f, tags in tqdm(df_test.values, miniters=1000):
    img = cv2.imread('input/test-jpg/{}.jpg'.format(f), -1) 
    x_test.append(cv2.resize(img, (img_size, img_size)))
    x_test  = np.array(x_test, np.float32)/255.
```

When i run the above code I get this error:

> error: OpenCV(3.4.3)
>   C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4044:
>   error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'

but the files there are in the directory and the path is rigth

Comment: Try to use absolute path instead of relative one (like `/home/fpi/input/test-jpg/...`or `C:/fpi/input/test-jpg`)

Comment: What's your img_size?

Comment: I reisize the images 64x64

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your input folder is located on the same level as your .py file. Otherwise, use abolute paths.

Also try the following to find your current working directory:

`import os
os.getcwd()`

check what is inside img after you do cv2.imread..

Comment: I'm sure that the folder is located properly. with the .tif images it works, but not with .jpg

Comment: I fixed my problem in another way. There was an error in a file that I read for labeling the images.